# Java: Download .txt File from URL

Tags: java, file, url, download, web

I want to download a .txt file from website and my code works, so I don't get an error and it loads the document, but the document is full of hmtl code, instead of my content.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL website = new URL("http://www.file-upload.net/download-11700212/document.txt.html");
        String filepath = "C://Users//" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "//Desktop//document.txt";

        ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        stream.getChannel().transferFrom(channel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        System.out.println("Download successfull.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Download was not successfull.");
    }
}
```

The download itself works, I got the txt file on my desktop, but the content is wrong and full of html code.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: this is the official link:

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11700212/document.txt.html

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are trying to download from is an HTML page, rather than the document itself. The link on that page you should be trying to download from is...

> http://www.file-upload.net/download5.php?valid=451.69031370715&id=11700212&name=document.txt

However, if you wish to guarantee that you're downloading a text file, then you should choose a text file to download directly e.g.

> http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt

Answer (score -2):

I have a Python project called [Python Webscraper](https://github.com/vmanikes/PythonWebScraper) which can read a URL and copy its textual contents to a text file without the HTML.

You'll need to install a package called [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) then run the code from the GitHub repo.

Comment: Rather than fixing english grammar, try to find the answer guys.